# Looping a telnet script

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, telnet

I have a network device that I need to automate logging into via telnet, pulling specific information, take that information and compare it to an excel spreadsheet. Which I have successfully been able to get python to do. The issue comes in when I try to loop this process, it errors out on the second go around. Also, I know there has to be a more efficient way to do this, keep in mind I have only been coding for a few weeks now.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import sys
import os
import telnetlib
import time

usnm = "Username"
pswd = "Password"
cmd_exit = "exit"
cmd_tty = "dmstty 11"
cmd_bang = "!!!!"
cmd_logi = "logi"
cmd_pass = "0000"
cmd_logo = "logo"
cmd_que_stn = "que stn "
cmd_oamp_dn = "oamp dn"
cmd_csel = "csel none"
cmd_star = "****"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("X.X.X.X" , "23", timeout = 5)

LG_WB = load_workbook('LEN_GWE.xlsx')
LG_SH = LG_WB.active

GWE = 0
OCM = 0

QUIT = 0
print("Loading...")
while QUIT == 0:
LEVEL_ONE = input('Type LEN, GWE, or PHONE: ')
if LEVEL_ONE == "GWE":
    LEVEL_TWO = input('GWE# ')
    for i in range(2, LG_SH.max_row+1):
        GWE_INPUT = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=6).value
        if GWE_INPUT == int(LEVEL_TWO):
            for x in range(1, 4):
                INFO = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=x).value
                print(INFO)
if LEVEL_ONE == "LEN":
    LEVEL_TWO = input('LEN# ')
    for i in range(2, LG_SH.max_row+1):
        LEN = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=5).value
        if LEN == int(LEVEL_TWO):
            for x in range(1, 4):
                INFO = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=x).value
                print(INFO)

if LEVEL_ONE == "PHONE":
    phone = input("TYPE PHONE# ")
    tn.read_until(b"user: ")
    tn.write((usnm + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"password: ")
    tn.write((pswd + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"$ ")
    tn.write((cmd_tty + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b" dmstty is starting....")
    tn.write((cmd_bang + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"  ! ")
    tn.write((cmd_logi + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"    PASS? ")
    tn.write((cmd_pass + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"  # ")
    tn.write((cmd_csel + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"  # ")
    tn.write((cmd_oamp_dn + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"    REQ   ")
    tn.write((cmd_que_stn + phone + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    output = tn.read_until(b"    REQ   ")
    file = open("log.txt", "w")
    file.write(str(output))
    file.close()
    tn.write((cmd_star + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"  # ")
    tn.write((cmd_logo + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.read_until(b"$ ")
    tn.write((cmd_exit + "\r\n").encode('ascii'))
    tn.close()
    read_log = open("log.txt", "r")
    new_log = open("new_log.txt", "w")
    with read_log as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                new_log.write(word + "\n")
    read_log.close()
    new_log.close()
    read_new = open("new_log.txt", "r")
    for line in read_new:
        if "GWE" in line:
            X = read_new.read()
            GWE_LOG = open("GWE_LOG.txt", "w")
            GWE_LOG.write(X)
            GWE_LOG.close()
            READ_GWE_LOG = open("GWE_LOG.txt", "r")
            with READ_GWE_LOG as f:
                PULL_GWE = f.readline()
                GWE = GWE + int(PULL_GWE)
                READ_GWE_LOG.close()
                for i in range(2, LG_SH.max_row+1):
                    GWE_INPUT = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=6).value
                    if GWE_INPUT == GWE:
                        for x in range(1, 4):
                            INFO = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=x).value
                            print(INFO)
                            GWE = 0
        if "OCMA" in line:
            print("LEN GROUP IS OCMA")
            X = read_new.readlines()
            OCM_LOG = open("OCM_LOG.txt", "w")
            OCM_LOG.writelines(X[2:])
            OCM_LOG.close()
            READ_OCM_LOG = open("OCM_LOG.txt", "r")
            with READ_OCM_LOG as f:
                PULL_OCM = f.readline()
                OCM = OCM + int(PULL_OCM)
                READ_OCM_LOG.close()
                for i in range(2, LG_SH.max_row+1):
                    LEN = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=5).value
                    if LEN == OCM:
                        for x in range(1, 4):
                            INFO = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=x).value
                            print(INFO)
                            OCM = 0
        if "OCMB" in line:
            print("LEN GROUP IS OCMB")
            X = read_new.readlines()
            OCM_LOG = open("OCM_LOG.txt", "w")
            OCM_LOG.writelines(X[2:])
            OCM_LOG.close()
            READ_OCM_LOG = open("OCM_LOG.txt", "r")
            with READ_OCM_LOG as f:
                PULL_OCM = f.readline()
                OCM = OCM + int(PULL_OCM)
                READ_OCM_LOG.close()
                for i in range(2, LG_SH.max_row+1):
                    LEN = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=5).value
                    if LEN == OCM:
                        for x in range(1, 4):
                            INFO = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=x).value
                            print(INFO)
                            OCM = 0
        if "OCMC" in line:
            print("LEN GROUP IS OCMC")
            X = read_new.readlines()
            OCM_LOG = open("OCM_LOG.txt", "w")
            OCM_LOG.writelines(X[2:])
            OCM_LOG.close()
            READ_OCM_LOG = open("OCM_LOG.txt", "r")
            with READ_OCM_LOG as f:
                PULL_OCM = f.readline()
                OCM = OCM + int(PULL_OCM)
                READ_OCM_LOG.close()
                for i in range(2, LG_SH.max_row+1):
                    LEN = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=5).value
                    if LEN == OCM:
                        for x in range(1, 4):
                            INFO = LG_SH.cell(row=i, column=x).value
                            print(INFO)
                            OCM = 0
```

When I try to do a second search I get the following error:
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYZDa.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it appears that the telnet connection is closed and hence the loop errors out.
The best way to debug this is to read every single line of output and try to figure out where the connection closes.

```
iter=0
while True:
    iter = iter + 1
    # Check for new line
    line = telnet.read_until(('\r\n').encode('ascii'), timeout=1)
    a = (line.decode("ascii"))
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
    if iter == 10:
        break
```

Use this code at many suspect points to see what output you missed with read_until.

good luck debugging!